# Drupal Module as web service with SSL

Tags: users, services, ssl

I need to create a SOAP web service that gets user-related information, but I want to secure the service with two-way ssl certificates (mutual authentication). I have created a module that does the Drupal user work, and I can access it by mapping a url to the function as usual, but I was wondering what is the best way to create a webservice in Drupal with mutual SSL authentication? Should I use Drupal modules/framework or just roll my own web service using SOAP calls? How do I expose this? I need to authenticate both the client and the web service, as both will be sending sensitive information.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "two-way ssl", so perhaps some links to more context would make it easier to answer the Drupal specific parts of your question.

Comment: Two-way SSL is when both the client and the webservice authenticate each other using SSL certificates. They can verify the other party by checking the message with the other parties public key to make sure that it actually was created by the other party.

Comment: Yeah, that much I could sort of figure out as well :) But the information you are asking for probably requires some level of understanding of how this is _implemented in general (or just any non-Drupal system)_ which I lack, and you haven't provided. I suggest you add that to the question.

Comment: To begin with the service and client would share each others public key certificates (*.cer) out-of-band. You would expose a SOAP service and a client endpoint, and configure ssl transport security on both, you would then indicate in whatever specific way for the framework you are using that you will only allow calls from people who have the opposing private key to the one each endpoint has by specifying how to find the certificate to check against either in the Certificate Store or on disk. I can do this successfully in WCF (C#)

Comment: So I want to be able to expose a service within drupal - are there any module hook points that I can hook into to set up a soap server or such (I don't want to use the Services module as the Soap Server isn't fit for production.) I am beginning to think that I have to do the SSL certificate checking in code with a 3rd party SOAP library such as WSO2 SOAP so I am looking for a hook to initiate my server in so that it is running all the time.